# SINGLE Invoice for 2 or more orders in magento

Tags: magento, invoice

It is possible to make an invoice for **2 or more orders** at the end of the month? I can see only to option to make invoice for every order.

If not, I'm looking for an extension to calculate the total in the printed PDF for 2 or more invoices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for one page for each invoice, or for an invoice that combines all orders? The mass action menu (the one where you check boxes in the order list and then use the dropdown to actually execute an action) will let you print multiples at once, and will concatenate each of them into the PDF.

If you want to combine the orders, you'll need to write some code of your own to coalesce the order details together before printing them.

---

The file you want to clone and work off of is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`. All of the `Order_Pdf_*` classes implement `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract`, so make sure you base off of that class as well.

On the controller level, look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::pdfinvoicesAction`, for code that should aggregate the orders and generate a PDF.

Comment: For example, I have a client that has 6-7 orders this a month. At the end of the month, I want to be able to select all the orders to make a SINGLE invoice. I'm aware of the of the concatenation when printing multiple invoices, but I'd like to write some custom code... please give more details.. thanks. (at least the option to sum the total of each invoice, in the last page, when combining invoices together in a PDF)

Comment: Take a look at the existing order generation. There's an order-specific header section, and then a simple loop for the order items. You should be able to collect all the order items together, then just write the appropriate header for the first order.

Comment: Where are the files used for generating an invoice from an order? I want to modify them to generate an invoice for 2 or more selected orders. (I would really like an extension like this, do you know where I can find some custom development or some help to build it from scratch?)

Comment: in magento the invoice is (stupidly) tied to order and ordered items, you might have some luck if at the end of the month you make a new order with all the items in previous orders and invoice this. Although i suggest you to export order data and invoice with accounting software

Comment: This really sucks... not even the glorious Enterprise Edition offer customization? At least an extension somewhere.. do you know where I can request a quote from a development team?

Comment: I suspect many of the Magento folks on this site (myself included) are probably freelancers, you may ask any of them, or take a look at magentocommerce.com for folks who have purchased into the partners program. :) That's not really a programming question, though, so this may not be the best forum to ask.